# Clickover does not hide on body click first opened

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, onclick, popover

I am using the bootstrapX clickover demo'ed here: http://www.leecarmichael.com/bootstrapx-clickover/examples.html

```
<img class="img-circle" src="something" alt="something" 
rel="clickover" 
onclick="loadData(this, somedata)" /> 


loadData(element, somedata){
      if(!$(element).attr('data-content')) {
         // build clickover flyout html
         $(element).clickover('show');
      } else {
         // do nothing clickover is already attached
      }


 }
```

This works... almost.

When I click the image element for the first time I have to close the clickover by clicking on the image otherwise it does not close even if I click open other clickovers or just click on the body of the page.

Any following clicks that show the clickover can be hidden by a click anywhere else which is how it should work. I have tried to close all other clickovers, unbind the click event and more with no success. I need to bind the `loadData` event in html and not in javascript as the clickover's onShown because this code runs in a loop and this data is specific to the element which is not very uniquely identifiable.

Any idea on how I could fix this?

Comment: Maybe bug is where you apply the data-content attribute to the element.

Comment: The data-content is applied fine. The clickover popup has all the right data.

Comment: Hmm I guess I will try some other control.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you describe seems the same for `global_close=0`.
`$(element).clickover('show');` don't set default options.

Use `$('.img-square').clickover().click();` in stead of `$('.img-square').clickover('show')`, see: http://bootply.com/66601 and https://github.com/lecar-red/bootstrapx-clickover/issues/42